# Segmentation Fault in a while loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

For a homework assignment, we're supposed to create a directed graph and free memory that no longer needs to be used. Where I seem to be running into trouble, now, is in the addition of vertices (which I'm verifying with GDB). What's troubling me, though, is that this problem is only occurring on half of the tests I have to pass, and I'm really just not quite sure why it's not occurring on all of them.

Main function (the  test):

```
int main(){
Graph graph;
const char *vertices_to_add[] = {"koala", "platypus", "snake", "salamander",
                                    "gecko", "frog", "dog", "hedgehog"};
int i;

for(i = 0; i < sizeof(vertices_to_add) / sizeof(vertices_to_add[0]); i++)
    add_vertex(&graph, vertices_to_add[i]);

clear_graph(&graph); /* works fine, from other methods passing */

return 0;
```

and then the `add_vertex`:

```
int add_vertex(Graph *graph, const char new_vertex[]){
Vertex *curr, *prev, *new_vert;

    if(graph == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (new_vertex == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (has_vertex(*graph, new_vertex) == 1)
        return 0;

    new_vert = malloc(sizeof(*curr));
    new_vert->name = malloc(strlen(new_vertex) * sizeof(char *));
    new_vert->name = strcpy(new_vert->name, new_vertex);

    if (graph->head == NULL){
        /* head case */
        graph->head = new_vert;
        return 1;
    }

    else{
        /* head != NULL */
        curr = graph->head;

        while (curr != NULL){
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next_vert;
        }

        prev->next_vert = new_vert;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the `has_vertex` method called:

```
int has_vertex(Graph graph, const char name[]){
Vertex *vertex;

if (graph.head == NULL)
    return 0;
if (name == NULL)
    return 0;

vertex = graph.head;

while (vertex != NULL){
    if (strcmp(vertex->name, name) == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        vertex = vertex->next_vert;
}
return 0;
}
```

The segfault error I'm getting seems to stem from the while loop in `has_vertex`, but I'm not too great with using GDB so I may be wrong. I'm genuinely just stumped that this is happening on 5/10 tests I have, but working on the other 5  just fine.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `add_vertex` function, you forgot to NULL the pointer to next vertex:

```
new_vert->next_vert = NULL;
```

also this line:

```
new_vert->name = malloc(strlen(new_vertex) * sizeof(char *));
```

is allocating more memory than necessary, it should be `(strlen(new_vertex) + 1 /* terminator */) * sizeof(char)`